# WLAN topology: does it work like a bus?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

Does wifi work as a star network with a switch or does it work like a bus ?

To be more precise, if I am in promiscuous mode, do I only see my traffic and broadcasted messages or do I get every packet sent on the network ?

I am talking about WPA protected networks.

Comment: You will see all packets, but you won't necessarily be able to decrypt them.

Comment: This is a networking question and not an InfoSec question (despite the potential implications for security)